# How do I add a user to Print Administrator group but not full administrator?

Tags: printing, administrator

He unplugged the printer and plugged it back in. OS X (10.6) asked for the print administrator password. I would like to add the user to that group but not the full administrators group. How do I do that?

This is for a stand-alone home Mac. By stand-alone I mean not part of a corporate login or administration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run this Terminal command (as an administrator), replacing "usersaccountname" with the user's actual account name:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -n /Local/Default -a usersaccountname -t user _lpadmin
```

When it prompts you, enter your password (it won't echo).  That user should now be able to administer printers.

Comment: Since this is 5yrs old, do you know if there has been an update by Apple on how to do this via the GUI in later versions of OSX ?

Comment: @sam Yes - Run the "Directory Utility" GUI app (search for it in Spotlight).  Choose 'Directory Editor' from the toolbar, then Viewing "Groups" in node /Local/Default. Then authenticate.  Then find "Print Administrators" in the left column list.  On the right, select "GroupMembership", then click the feint "+" to the right of the Value column.  Edit "new_value" to the user's account name then click Save.